# Grouping elements with java

Tags: java, grouping

I have

```
b a, 
c b, 
c a, 
d e
```

pairs and as an output want to print

```
a - group 1, 
b - group 1, 
c - group 1, 
d - group 2, 
e - group 2
```

Could you please give some hints, how to solve this problem with java.
Thanks!

Comment: Did you try anything ?

Comment: Seems like a job for Union Find-Disjoint Set or Depth First Search.

Comment: Thanks for your replies!
I am trying to do this with arrayList by contains() method, but unfortunately can't find the optimal solution. Also, I am thinking to do this with JDBC by creating a table and using SQL queries, but I can't find an appropriate query statement!

Comment: Why do you need JDBC (or database) for this ?

Comment: Please explain more clearly exactly what you want. For example, if there was another pair "d b" what would you want to print then?

Comment: @Apurv: I guess if I use JDBC, it would be easier to do that by comparing the columns.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon: I want to have finally an output where I can see the group of each element. For example, there was a pair "d b", the output would be "d - Group 1", because "b" is in "Group 1" already.
In other words, for the first pair the group is always "Group 1", afterwards if in the second row there is an element from the first row (in this case 2nd row has b, which was in 1st row as well), then it belongs to the same group as the first pair and so on.
Thanks!

Comment: When I saw this question, I was very tempted to copy your output, and then just write a program hardcoded which printed that output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use an `List<Set<String>>`.

For each pair, scan your array of groups to find if either of the pair is already in the group. If it is then add the other.

After adding one or other of the pair to a group, you need to do another scan to see if the added one exists in another group. If it does you must merge both groups.

If neither item of the pair is found, you've got a new group, add both to it and add it to your list.

This code seems to work:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    new Test().test();
  }
  // Might be better to use a LinkedList here.
  List<Set<String>> groups = new ArrayList<>();

  // Keeps track of what we added and where.
  private static class Added {
    final int where;
    final String what;

    public Added(int where, String what) {
      this.where = where;
      this.what = what;
    }
  }

  // Add if allowed.
  Added add(Set<String> group, int where, String has, String what) {
    if (group.contains(has)) {
      group.add(what);
      return new Added(where, what);
    }
    return null;
  }

  void addPair(String a, String b) {
    // Is ether of the strings in any of the existing groups.
    Added added = null;
    for (int i = 0; added == null && i < groups.size(); i++) {
      Set<String> group = groups.get(i);
      added = add(group, i, a, b);
      if (added == null) {
        added = add(group, i, b, a);
      }
    }
    if (added != null) {
      // Merge any now-joined groups.
      for (int i = added.where + 1; i < groups.size(); i++) {
        Set<String> group = groups.get(i);
        if (group.contains(added.what)) {
          // Join them.
          groups.get(added.where).addAll(group);
          groups.remove(group);
          // There shouldn't be any more.
          break;
        }
      }
    } else {
      // New group - May be better to use a TreeSet here for print order.
      Set<String> group = new HashSet<>();
      group.add(a);
      group.add(b);
      groups.add(group);
    }
  }

  void printGroups(String title) {
    System.out.println(title);
    for (int i = 0; i < groups.size(); i++) {
      System.out.println("Group " + (i + 1) + "=" + groups.get(i));
    }
  }

  public void test() {
    addPair("b", "a");
    addPair("c", "b");
    addPair("c", "a");
    addPair("d", "e");
    printGroups("Test-1");
    addPair("d", "b");
    printGroups("Test-2");
  }
}
```

It prints:

```
Test-1
Group 1=[b, c, a]
Group 2=[d, e]
Test-2
Group 1=[d, e, b, c, a]
```

Comment: Thanks!
I think there are errors in the code.

Comment: @ArmMiner - Please describe the errors - it works fine for me.

Comment: Maybe something is wrong with my eclipse, the errors are the following:
-- Illegal modifier for the class Added; only public, abstract & final are permitted
-- line 25: groups cannot be resolved
-- line 46: Cannot instantiate the type HashSet<?>

Comment: Ahh! Ok, I only posted the relevant code. I've now posted the whole class.

Comment: I am using Java 7 - you may need to adjust the generics where you see "<>" if you are using Java --7.

Comment: Thank you very much! 
It works normally.

Comment: @ArmMiner - Thanks best supported by an upvote. :) ... You're welcome, that was interesting.

Comment: Actually I was trying to vote up, but my reputation score is 6 (to vote up I have to have at least 15). :)

Comment: Sorry, one more thing!
What do you think if I covert set<String> to a list as follows:
in a loop
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(groups.get(i));

Comment: The point of using a `Set` is that if you add the same string to it twice it will not change the set. Duplicates are ignored. If you use a List you will have to achieve that functionality some other way. What benefit do you see from using a List here?

Comment: I just want to make the output without the brackets and in 2 columns:
1st column would be the the elements from a to e and in the 2nd column the corresponding group.

Comment: Look at `printGroups`. It should be obvious once you understand the structure.

Comment: In PrintGroups it iterates over Groups and gives the output. The problem is that if I want to convert the List set string to list of strings I will not be able to iterate in the same loop because of the different lengths. Sorry for so many questions!

Comment: @ArmMiner - Sorry but I think you should work it out.

Answer (score 0):

Use TreeMap<String, Group> where the key is the element name (a, b ..) and the value is the group (can contain the group number and anything else you need to know about it).

Try to locate the group first. If none can be found, create and put a new group into the map. At the end, just iterate over entry set to print the key-value pairs.

I will not post the code for you as this looks like a homework.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
one question: if I use the treeMap, each element will have unique group right? Because as you can see from the post more than one elements can have the same group.

Comment: Initially at least two elements in the same row of the input should be mapped into the same group. Later this group also expands to take the unassigned element from the pair where one of the members is already assigned to that group.